# Audit using AspectJ after spring PreAuthorize on controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, aop, audit

I'm trying to audit log both successful and failing OAuth2 authentication attempts in a Spring application. I'm making use of Spring's @PreAuthorize annotation as shown below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
public Person getById(@PathVariable String id) {
    return service.getById(id);
}
```

The authentication and authorization works fine. In an attempt to do audit logging, I tried doing some AOP with AspectJ as shown below.

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class AuditLogger {


    @After("@annotation(org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize)")
    public void afterAuth(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        // do audit logging

    }

}
```

However, this only gets hit when authentication and authorization are both successful. These are the scenarios:

- Given valid token with read scope - afterAuth is hit
- Given invalid token - afterAuth not hit
- Given valid token without read scope - afterAuth not hit

My best guess is that Spring does something differently when authentication or authorization fails, but I'm not sure how to get around it. Any advice?

Comment: Those are already logged through events... You can simply create an `ApplicationListener` and listen to the appropriate events. No need for AspectJ. Also `@After` will not work, as it will execute after a method annotated with `@PreAuthorize`  has finished executing.

Comment: I looked at that and found the below events happening for the scenarios. I wanted to be able to do the same thing no matter what happened, but I guess I'll have to handle it differently since the events are different.
 Valid with scope: AuthenticationSuccessEvent, AuditApplicationEvent, PublicInvocationEvent, ServletRequestHandledEvent
 Invalid: AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent, AuditApplicationEvent
 Valid without scope: AuthenticationSuccessEvent, AuditApplicationEvent, PublicInvocationEvent, AuthorizationFailureEvent, AuditApplicationEvent, ServletRequestHandledEvent

Comment: I also tried using both Before and Around as AspectJ annotations and had the same issue, so it's not because I used After.

Comment: Spring Security has 2 main classes for event either `AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent` for failures or `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` or `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccesEvent`. For Authentication it is the `AuthenticationFailureEvent` if you are jus interested in logging them you can use the super class `AbstractAuthorizationEvent` and `AbstractAuthenticationEvent`... You don't need the other ones as those aren't related to security.

Comment: True, but I also need to audit log what the request the user attempted was, whether or not they actually had authorization. So it's not just authentication that I'm auditing. I think I'm going to try and implement the ApplicationListener and handle AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent, AuthorizationFailureEvent, and ServletRequestHandledEvent. I'll post the solution if I get it to work.

Comment: Which is part of the `WebDetails` which is set on the `Authentication` object in the given events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find a good way to do this in one file, so I ended up using one file to handle failed auth requests (using events) and another to handle successful auth requests (using aspects). I annotated all of my controllers with a custom MyAnnotation that contained some information about the controller. This might not be the best solution, but hopefully it helps someone out.

Failed:

```
@Component
public class FailedAuthRequestAuditor {

    private ApplicationContext context;
    private AuditEventLogger logger;

    @Autowired
    public FailedAuthRequestAuditor(
        ApplicationContext context,
        AuditEventLogger logger
    ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onBadCredentialsEvent(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event) {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        Method destinationMethod = this.getDestination(request);

        if (destinationMethod != null) {
            // do logging here
        }
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onAuthorizationFailureEvent(AuthorizationFailureEvent event) {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        Method destinationMethod = this.getDestination(request);

        if (destinationMethod != null) {
            // do logging here
        }
    }


    private Method getDestination(HttpServletRequest request) {
        for (HandlerMapping handlerMapping : context.getBeansOfType(HandlerMapping.class).values()) {
            HandlerExecutionChain handlerExecutionChain = null;
            try {
                handlerExecutionChain = handlerMapping.getHandler(request);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // do nothing
            }

            if (handlerExecutionChain != null && handlerExecutionChain.getHandler() instanceof HandlerMethod) {
                return ((HandlerMethod) handlerExecutionChain.getHandler()).getMethod();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Successful:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SuccessfulAuthRequestAuditor {

    private AuditEventLogger auditEventLogger;
    private AuditEventOutcomeMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    public SuccessfulAuthRequestAuditor(AuditEventLogger auditEventLogger, AuditEventOutcomeMapper mapper) {
        this.auditEventLogger = auditEventLogger;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(@com.company.MyAnnotation * *(..)) && @annotation(myAnnotation) && args(request,..)", returning = "result")
    public void afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result, MyAnnotation myAnnotation, HttpServletRequest request) {
        // do logging
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(@com.company.MyAnnotation * *(..)) && @annotation(myAnnotation) && args(request,..)", throwing = "exception")
    public void afterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable exception, MyAnnotation myAnnotation, HttpServletRequest request) {
        // do logging
    }
}
```